# jQuery Datatable with MVC 5 and Entity Framework

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, datatables

I need some guidance on what to put in my controller so that I can use server-side processing with my jQuery datatables. I am using MVC 5 and Entity Framework.

The example at: http://datatablesmvc.codeplex.com/documentation states the following:

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult GetDataTables(DataTable dataTable) {
  List<List<string>> table = new List<List<string>>();
  //Do something with dataTable and fill table    
  return new DataTableResult(dataTable, table.Count, table.Count, table);
   }
 }
```

But what do I do when I am using LINQ such as this?

```
 public ActionResult Index()
         {
           var activity = db.Activity.Include(a => a.ActivityType);
              return View(activity.ToList());
          }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## ------------------------------- Updated answer -------------------------------

#### Why the update?

This answer seems to keep getting much attention from SO users and I thought everyone could benefit from a "little" update.

#### What's changed so far?

`DataTables.Mvc` started over an year ago. It has changed and now it's called `DataTables.AspNet`. But that's not all.

At that time, aim was to help with base classes. Problem is that you'd just get a zip and should manually merge all that into your project. Also, there was no binder for models and integration was really boring.

Now we have a modular architecture with Nuget packages to help. You can either reference `Core` package and implement everything yourself or you can get apropriate packages (`Mvc5` or `AspNet`; `WebApi2` is comming soon) with native model binders, one-line registration and a full test suite.

#### How to get started?

Check out `samples` folder on `dev` branch ([click here](https://github.com/ALMMa/datatables.aspnet/tree/dev/samples)).
Don't forget to get appropriate Nuget packages. You can find a list of them [here](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/almma).

## ------------------------------- Original answer -------------------------------

#### First things first

You can either use DataTables 1.9, 1.10 with old API or 1.10 with the new API.

If you choose the new API (1.10 only) than you'll miss some plugins here and there but you can use [DataTables.AspNet on GitHub](https://github.com/ALMMa/datatables.aspnet) to help with the bindings.

If not, you can take a look and change the code to match request variables from other versions (support will be provided later on my project).

#### The real-deal

Point is that you'll have to handle three items:

1. Global filter/search
2. Column filter/search
3. Column sort

#### Gimme some code!

That might change from which version and if you're using (or not) my binding class. Consider that you're using it, for the sake of avoiding handling request parameters here, ok?

So, you can play with something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index([ModelBinder(typeof(DataTablesBinder))] IDataTablesRequest requestParameters)
{
    var totalCount = myDbContext.Set<Something>().Count();
    var filteredDataSet = myDbContext.Set<Something>().Where(_s => _s.ToLower().Contains(requestParameters.Search.Value));

    foreach(var column in requestParameters.Columns.GetFilteredColumns())
    {
        // Apply individual filters to each column.
        // You can try Dynamic Linq to help here or you can use if statements.

        // DynamicLinq will be slower but code will be cleaner.
    }

    var isSorted = false;
    IOrderedEnumerable<Something> ordered = null;
    foreach(var column in requestParameters.Columns.GetSortedColumns())
    {
        // If you choose to use Dynamic Linq, you can apply all sorting at once.
        // If not, you have to apply each sort manually, as follows.

        if (!isSorted)
        {
            // Apply first sort.
            if (column.SortDirection == Column.SortDirection.Ascendant)
                ordered.OrderBy(...);
            else
                ordered.OrderByDescending(...);

            isSorted = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (column.SortDirection == Column.SortDirection.Ascendant)
                ordered.ThanBy(...);
            else
                ordered.ThanByDescending(...);
        }
    }

    var pagedData = ordered.Skip(requestParameters.Start).Take(requestParameters.Length);

    var dataTablesResult = new DataTablesResult(
        requestParameters.Draw,
        pagedData,
        filteredDataSet.Count(),
        totalCount
    );

    return View(dataTablesResult);
}
```

Comment: I saw this on the blogs from https://datatables.net and it looks really good. Do you have an example with dynamic linq?

Comment: Sorry, not yet. I'll be working on it today/tomorrow and make it available soon. However, should be quite simple though: create some sort of helper/extension to receive column collection and return a string with either filter or sort and pass it to Dynamic Linq.

Comment: Just been playing around with it a bit more and i don't think it will work with the approach I'm taking as the IModelBinder interface won't work with ApiControllers. I don't suppose you have a suggestion for an alternative/patch?

Comment: Good think for provider here rather than seprate project

Answer (score 0):

Use [EFDatatable](https://github.com/ekondur/EFDatatable)

#### What is EFDatatable?

EFDatatable is a helper to create a grid with Jquery Datatable and provides an extension to retrive data generically from Entity Framework context. It possible to use many datatable.js features with Html helper. It gives serverside or client side options. There's more: [Wiki Documentation](https://github.com/ekondur/EFDatatable/wiki)

```cs
@(Html.EF().Datatable<Person>()
        .Name("PersonGrid")
        .Columns(cols =>
        {
            cols.Field(a => a.Id).Visible(false);
            cols.Field(a => a.Name).Title("First Name").Class("text-danger");
            cols.Field(a => a.Age).Title("Age").Searchable(false);
            cols.Field(a => a.BirthDate).Title("Birth Date").Format("DD-MMM-Y");
            cols.Command(a => a.Id, "onClick", text: "Click").Title("");
        })
        .Filters(filter =>
        {
            filter.Add(a => a.Id).GreaterThanOrEqual(1);
        })
        .URL(Url.Action("GetDataResult"), "POST")
        .ServerSide(true)
        .Render()
)
```

With "ToDataResult(request)" extension function, data can get with server side pagination very simply.

```cs
public JsonResult GetDataResult(DataRequest request)
    {
        DataResult result = context.People.ToDataResult(request);
        return Json(result);
    }
```

#### Where can I get it?

Install [EFDatatable](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EFDatatable/) from the package manager console:

```
PM> Install-Package EFDatatable
```

Then add [datatables.net](https://datatables.net/) Javascript and CSS files or links to your project.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```