# How to implement datatables in asp.net mvc?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables-1.10

SO I have an entity called product as follow:

```
public class Product
    {
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)]
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
        public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string SubCategory { get; set; }
    }
```

I have another class called `EFProductRepository` which is derived from another class called `IProductRepository` as following:

```
public class EFProductRepository : IProductRepository
    {
        private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();
        public IEnumerable<Product> Products
        {
            get { return context.Products; }
        }
    }
```

Then in my controller action `Index` i have this:

```
public ViewResult Index()
        {
            return View(repository.Products);
        }
```

and a view for index which list the data in a table, SO the question is how can i implement the DataTable client side to this piece of code? i tried this here [jQuery Datatable with MVC 5 and Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466041/jquery-datatable-with-mvc-5-and-entity-framework#comment36037955_22522401) but no luck unfortunately.
Any help is appreciated, Regards.

Comment: I assume the datatable plugin expects data in JSON format. convert your context.Products to JSON format ( may be after mapping them to a list of view models which has properties which the plugin is looking for)

Comment: @Shyju any hint on how to change it to JSON?

Comment: there is a `Controller.Json` method you can use.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to convert your object to JSON and mess with all that controller customization, I would suggest checking out this data table that I use in my MVC 5 projects.  https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/ This will give you a lot of functionality you may want on the front end anyways, and it just directly binds to a list of objects.

There are easy getting started guides under the documentation.

Good luck

Comment: Looks like a good alternative, I can't accept this as answer but i up voted it. I really need to get on DataTables ;)